# How to create IBAction in xcode 8 for iOS 10

Tags: swift, ios10, xcode8

When i create IBAction in xcode8 using swift. it gives error at run time. Unrecognised Selector sent to UIButton

Comment: Please add more information. It is very hard to answer this question currently.

Comment: thnx for reply.please check link

Comment: This is not an Xcode 8 specific problem. It is the same as Xcode 7. I would be good if you could include what you have tried and have a look around before going straight to stack overflow.

Comment: i'm just creating IBoutle from story board. and it gives error like this.....unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`@IBAction func myFunc(sender: AnyObject)`

becomes

`@IBAction func myFunc(_ sender: AnyObject)`

Comment: @IBAction func myFunc(withSender sender: AnyObject)

Answer (score 2):

`@IBAction func myFunc(_ sender: Any?)`

Making the `sender` an optional in Swift, will guarantee your code not to crash if ever the `sender` is `nil` (which may be possible if you have legacy ObjC code doing `[self myFunc:nil]`, which I've seen many times in various codebases…).